# NuGet: Could not install package VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, emgucv

I'm using Visual Studio 2013. I create a new project Windows Form Application (C#), with target framework in tab Application in Properties of the my project: .NET Framework 3.5.
When I open NuGet and search EmguCV and click install show this error:

```
Installing 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1'.
Successfully installed 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1'.
Adding 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1' to RadarOCR.Desktop.
Uninstalling 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1'.
Successfully uninstalled 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'VVVV.EmguCV 2.4.2.1'. You are trying to install this package 
into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain 
any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
```

I do not know what's wrong! Help-me please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you what the problem is:

> You are trying to install this package 
>   into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5', but the package does not contain 
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

The VVVV.EmguCV NuGet package does not support being installed into a project that targets .NET 3.5.

Looking inside the VVVV.EmguCV NuGet package it has custom MSBuild target files for .NET 4.0 and no other .NET framework version. So if you want to install it you would need to change your project so it targets .NET 4.0 or higher.

Comment: I tried that, but does not solve my problem. Shows the same error message.

Comment: I have successfully installed the VVVV.EmguCV NuGet package into a .NET 4.0 project. If it is giving you the same error message then the project is still targeting .NET 3.5